# Angular Pipe: value !== value

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

Can someone explain why [inside Angular's](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L171) `DataPipe` there is this expression: `value !== value`. In which case this does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case in which (x !== x) is true is when x is **NaN**.

See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: Any condition check with a `NaN` will return `false`, thus `value === value` is `false` iff `value` is `NaN`.

Comment: Why `value !== value` instead of `isNaN(value)`?